# Get data from two collections in Firebase flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have two collections which are called Users and Employee. I need to get data from specific field from those collections. "Users" and "Employee" collections have the same field like "password". I have been trying to get the password from Users and Employee collections and use it to navigate me different screen . My codes:

```
QuerySnapshot snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection ("Employee").where ('id', isEqualTo: id).get();
QuerySnapshot snap2 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection ("Users").where ('uid', isEqualTo: id).get();


print(snap.docs[0]['id']);
print(snap2.docs[0]['uid']);
User.employeeId = id;

try {
  if (password == snap.docs[0]['password'] ) {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    sharedPreferences.setString('employeeId', id).then((_){
      navigateNext(HomeScreen());
    });
    }else if (password == snap2.docs[0]['upassword']) {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    sharedPreferences.setString('userId', id).then((_){
      navigateNext(AdminScreen());
    });
```

error:
E/flutter ( 7498): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter ( 7498): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
E/flutter ( 7498): #1      _LoginScreenState.build. (package:attendanceapp/loginscreen.dart:126:38)
E/flutter ( 7498): 
E/flutter ( 7498):

Comment: `.collection ("Users").where ('uid', isEqualTo: id).get();`. The `Users` document you're showing doesn't have a `uid` field, so that query will never return anything. Are you sure it shouldn't be filtering on `id`, which *is* a field in the document?

Comment: sorry, select wrong pic..i update question ..

Comment: Now if you run this code in the debugger and check the value of each variable on each line, which is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: failed to navigate to the two screen ..no get data from Users or Employee collections..output '''                                                                                                       E/flutter ( 6559): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter ( 6559): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
E/flutter ( 6559): #1      _LoginScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:attendanceapp/loginscreen.dart:126:39)
E/flutter ( 6559): <asynchronous suspension>'''

Comment: Ah, you get an error message - that is good to know. Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to add this information, and indicate the exact line in your code that throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

I saw there is a collection inside the document(Users or Employee), I am not sure whether you could get them properly.
Here is my code with a similar setup as you posted. If you could not get the data properly, I recommended you to assign the value to variable "id" before getting value from FirebaseFirestore.

I normally desiged a button for debugging. Hope it could help you.

```dart
  void getMessagesTest222() async{
    final id = "1";
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _firestore.collection('User').where('uid', isEqualTo: id).get();
    final allData1 = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.get('uid')).toList();
    final allData2 = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.get('upassword')).toList();
    print('uid = >$allData1');
    print('upassword = > $allData2');
  }
```

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Record'),
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, creationCategory.id);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
            onPressed: () async {
              getMessagesTest222();
              // await getData();
              // await getMessagesTestTest();
              // Navigator.push(
              //   context,
              //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ItemDetailsScrrent()),
              // );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[

              Text('Trahs Collection',
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black38, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 40),
              ),
              ItemStream(),
            ],
          ),
          ),
      ),
      );

  }
```

Fig1.Firebase structure
[image]

Fig2.print out the data from firestore
[image]

Updated Code for the second question from this user.

As you mentioned, you created two pages that are for different users
We could get the data to make sure whether this account is existing, and then we could create two **if loops** to login to different pages.

```dart
            RoundButton(
              title: 'Log In',
              colour: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              onPressed: () async{
                try {
                  final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
                  // if (user != null) {
                  //   // Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                  //   Navigator.pushNamed(context, RecordScreen.id);
                  // }
                  if (user.user?.email.toString() == 'add@123.com') {
                    // Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, administrors.id);
                  }
                  if (user.user?.email.toString() == 'operator@123.com') {
                    // Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, user.id);
                  }

                }
                catch(e) {
                  print(e);
                }
              },
            ),
```

Comment: I/flutter (20987): uid = >1
I/flutter (20987): upassword = > 1
E/flutter (20987): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter (20987): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
E/flutter (20987): #1      _LoginScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:attendanceapp/loginscreen.dart:139:38)
E/flutter (20987): <asynchronous suspension>

Comment: i have a problem that i want to uses this Users data to login to admin screen ..and use employee to login to home screen

Comment: I've updated my code, please check it above. Thanks.

Comment: i want to use data from employee collection to navigate me to user screen and use data at Users collection to navigate me to admin screen ..i still can not solve it

Comment: @mahmoudkotb Could you update your question about your current situation?